# Minium value of a stack in C

Tags: arrays, c, stack

i'm trying to implement a funcion who calculate the minium value of a stack in C implemented with an array, using only push() and pop() function.
here is my code: (findMin() is the last function).

The function doesn't work, if i put 5 3 5 5 5 in the stack, it prints "minium value 1". I think it's because i can't find a correct base condition

```
void init(int S[]){
    S[0] = 0;
}

int push(int S[], int x) {
    
    if(!fullStack(S)){
        S[0] = S[0] + 1;
        S[S[0]] = x;
    }
    else printf("stack full\n");

}

int pop(int S[]) {
    if(!emptyStack(S)){
        int x = S[S[0]];
        S[0]--;
        return x;
    }
    else {
        printf("stack empty\n");
        return -1;
    }
}

int emptyStack(int S[]) {
    return S[0] == 0;
}


int fullStack(int S[]) {
    return S[0] == SIZE;
}
int findMin(int S[]){
    if(emptyStack(S)) return ;
    else{
        int x = pop(S);
        if(x < findMin(S)) return x;
        else return findMin(S); 
        push(S, x);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Something does not work correctly? (What is it?) See also: [ask], [mre]

Comment: `if(x < findMin(S)) return x;` consumes the entire stack. The subsequent `else return findMin(S); ` is running on an empty stack. `findMin(empty)` returns something undefined. `push(S, x);` is unreachable.

Comment: Use a starting value of INT_MAX, and if the found values are less than that, you assign the value to x.

Comment: At least some of the visible issues would be reported as compiler warnings. Make sure you are compiling with warnings enabled, read and fix them.

Comment: If this is school homework, I would think that the stack should also be unmodified after finding the minimum value. You can accomplish this by using a second stack and push all the popped values onto that one. After the minimum value have been found restore the original stack from the saved data.

Comment: @SvenNilsson I think that's what the `push(S, x);` was meant to accomplish.

Comment: @SvenNilsson is a university "homework", the exercise doesn't allow me to create a second stack, just pop, push recorsively..

Comment: yes, the function must leave the stack unmodified also

Comment: Random notes so far: compile with warnings, INT_MAX is a great default for `findMin(empty)`, best only call `findMin(S)` recursively once, no more code is executed in a function after you reach a `return`.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree that the failure to handle the recursion base case properly is the origin of your issue.  Other comments offer good suggestions about that.

Comment: I just do something like this:                                                                                        
 `int findMin(int S[]){
 if(emptyStack(S)) return 100000;
 else{
  int x = pop(S);
  int min = findMin(S);
  if(x < min) return x;
  else return min; 
 }
 
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting logic...

By what i could understand, here is what you need to do,

```
#define LARGE_NUMBER 1000; //You could look into INT_MAX

int findMin(int S[]){
    if(emptyStack(S)) return LARGE_NUMBER; 
    else{
        int x = pop(S);
        int y = findMin(S); // Store result in separate variable to return
        if(x < y) return x;
        else return y; 
        push(S, x); // This is unreachable code, so stack becomes empty
    }
    
}
```

After these changes, findMin() returns "3" in your case when input is "5 3 5 5 5".

Comment: yes, after some testing i wrote the same code, but with putting "push(S,x)" after "y=findMin(S)" so the stack can be filled again!